# Unable to select whole mesh in edit mode

Tags: mesh

[image: Modifiers][image: Mesh selection issue]

Hi All,

There is probably a very simple answer to this. However when I enter edit mode I am unable to select my who mesh, only the ring of faces as shown below.

What am I doing wrong.

Cheers Aaron.

Comment: Could you post image with Modifiers tab selected? It's probably because this mesh is generated by some of them (modifiers).

Comment: Hi LukeD, Please see attached, The only modifier I have active is a mirror.

Comment: Well... Could you please upload blend file with this object to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'll check it.

Comment: You are in Face select mode but I don't see any faces on your model except for the ones in the highlighted ring.  What happens when you go to Vertex Select mode?  What does the model look like with Solid Shading enabled instead of Wireframe?

Comment: I think you have hidden most of your mesh - Alt-H - to unhide it.

Comment: Please share blend file as well. You're right, there's probably a simple answer for this--you might have the 'Alt' key action active for some reason (either the key is stuck in the keyboard, or through some stylus/input device settings accidentally enabled).

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple problem. Other faces of the mesh were hidden.

The answer was to unhide them with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in Edit mode